# Partial derivative of recursive exponential $f(x) = \sum^{K_2}_{k_2=1}c_{k_2} \exp(-z^{(2)}_{k2})$ with respect to the deepest parameter

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

I was trying to take the derivative of the following equation (which can be depicted nicely in a tree like structure, look at the end of question for diagram):

$$f(x) = f([x_1, ..., x_{N_p}])= \sum^{K_2}_{k_2=1}c_{k_2} \exp(-z^{(2)}_{k_2})$$

with respect to some parameters $\theta$ (which are not explicit above). As you can notice, the vector $x$ can be subdivided in parts: $x = [x_1, ..., x_{N_p}] \in \mathbb{R}^N$. Each $x_i \in \mathbb{R}^{D_p}$ and there are $N_p$ of them (hence, $N = N_p D_p$).

Let me explain how $\theta$ is present in the above equation. For that let me define:
$$ a^{(3)}_{k_2} = \exp(-z^{(2)}_{k_2}) \ , \ k_2 \in \{ 1, ..., K_2 \} $$
$$ z^{(2)}_{k_2} = \| a^{(2)} - t_{k_2}^{(2)} \|^2 \ , \ \ k_2 \in \{ 1, ..., K_2 \}$$
where $a^{(2)} \in \mathbb{R}^{K_1}$ and $t^{(2)}_{k_2} \in \mathbb{R}^{K_1} $. $a^{(2)}$ can also be divided in parts as follow: 
$$ a^{(2)} = \left(
\begin{array}{c}
a^{(2)}_{1,1}\\
\vdots \\
a^{(2)}_{1,D_d}\\
\vdots \\
a^{(2)}_{n_p,1}\\
\vdots \\
a^{(2)}_{n_p,D_d}\\
\vdots \\
a^{(2)}_{N_p,1}\\
\vdots \\
a^{(2)}_{N_p,D_d}\\
\end{array}
\right) $$
which leads to the following notation:
$$ a^{(2)}_{n_p,k} = \exp(-z^{(1)}_{n_p,k}) \ , \ n_p \in \{1,...,N_p\} \ , \ k \in \{1,...,D_d\} $$ 
$$ z^{(1)}_{n_p, k} = \| a^{(1)}_{n_p} - t^{(1)}_{n_p, k} \|^2  \ , \ n_p \in \{1,...,N_p\} \ , \ k \in \{1,...,D_d\}$$
$$ a^{(1)}_{n_p} = x_{n_p} \ , \ n_p \in \{1,...,N_p\} $$

and $a^{(1)}_{n_p} = x_{n_p} \in \mathbb{R}^{D_p}$ and $ t^{(1)}_{n_p, k} \in \mathbb{R}^{D_p}$. The parameters are $\theta = \{ c, t_{k_2}^{(2)}, t^{(1)} \}$.

After that I tried taking partial derivatives with respect to the lowest level in the equation $t^{(1)}$. i.e. I did $\frac{\partial f(x) }{\partial t^{(1)}_{i,j}}$ and got:

$$ \frac{\partial f(x) }{\partial t^{(1)}_{i,j}} = \sum^{K_2}_{k_2 = 1} c_{k_2} (- \exp(-z^{(2)}_{k_2}))(2(a^{(2)}_{i,j} - [t^{(2)}_{k_2}]_{i,j}))(-\exp(-z^{(1)}_{i,j}))2(x_i - t^{(1)}_{i,j})(-1)$$

But wasn't sure if it was correct.

In fact, let me show you how I derived the above equation. Consider:

$$ \frac{\partial f(x) }{ \partial t^{(1)}_{i,j} } = \frac{\partial f(x) }{ \partial z^{(1)}_{i,j} } \frac{\partial z^{(1)}_{i,j}}{ \partial t^{(1)}_{i,j} }  = \left( \frac{\partial f(x) }{ \partial a^{(2)}_{i,j} } \frac{\partial a^{(2)}_{i,j} }{ \partial z^{(1)}_{i,j} } \right) \frac{\partial z^{(1)}_{i,j}}{ \partial t^{(1)}_{i,j} } $$

holds since:

$$  \frac{\partial f(x) }{ \partial z^{(1)}_{i,j} } = \frac{\partial f(x) }{ \partial a^{(2)}_{i,j} } \frac{\partial a^{(2)}_{i,j} }{ \partial z^{(1)}_{i,j} }$$

Now, to evaluate the above, we require the chain rule for $\frac{\partial f(x) }{ \partial a^{(2)}_{i,j} } $, hence:

$$\frac{\partial f(x) }{ \partial a^{(2)}_{i,j} }  = \sum^{K_2}_{k_2=1} \frac{\partial f(x) }{ \partial z^{(2)}_{k_2}  } \frac{\partial z^{(2)}_{k_2}  }{ \partial a^{(2)}_{i,j} }  =  \sum^{K_2}_{k_2=1} \frac{\partial f(x) }{ \partial a^{(3)}_{k_2}  } \frac{\partial a^{(3)}_{k_2}  }{ \partial z^{(2)}_{k_2} } \frac{\partial z^{(2)}_{k_2}  }{ \partial a^{(2)}_{i,j} } $$

now consider each equation seperately one can see that:

$$ \frac{\partial f(x) }{ \partial a^{(3)}_{k_2}  } = c_{k_2}$$
 $$ \frac{\partial a^{(3)}_{k_2}  }{ \partial z^{(2)}_{k_2} } = -\exp(-z^{(2)})$$
 $$ \frac{\partial z^{(2)}_{k_2}  }{ \partial a^{(2)}_{i,j} } = 2(a^{(2)}_{i,j} - [t_{k_2}^{(2)}]_{i,j})(1)$$

hence $\frac{\partial f(x) }{ \partial a^{(2)}_{i,j} }$ is:

$$ \frac{\partial f(x) }{ \partial a^{(2)}_{i,j} } =  \sum^{K_2}_{k_2=1}  c_{k_2} ( -\exp(z^{(2)})) 2(a^{(2)}_{i,j} - [t_{k_2}^{(2)}]_{i,j})(1) $$

and

$$ \frac{\partial a^{(2)}_{i,j} }{ \partial z^{(1)}_{i,j} } = -\exp(-z^{(1)}_{i,j}) $$

hence $ \frac{\partial f(x) }{ \partial z^{(1)}_{i,j} } $:

$$ \frac{\partial f(x) }{ \partial z^{(1)}_{i,j} } =  \left( \sum^{K_2}_{k_2=1}  c_{k_2} ( -\exp(z^{(2)})) 2(a^{(2)}_{i,j} - [t_{k_2}^{(2)}]_{i,j})(1)  \right) (-\exp(-z^{(1)}_{i,j})) $$

$$\frac{\partial z^{(1)}_{i,j}}{ \partial t^{(1)}_{i,j} }  = 2(x_i - t^{(1)}_{i,j})(-1)$$

which finally gives the equation that we wanted:

$$ \frac{\partial f(x) }{\partial t^{(1)}_{i,j}}  = (2(x_i -t^{(1)}_{i,j})(-1)) \left( \sum^{K_2}_{k_2=1}  c_{k_2} ( -\exp(z^{(2)})) 2(a^{(2)}_{i,j} - [t_{k_2}^{(2)}]_{i,j})(1)  \right) (-\exp(-z^{(1)}_{i,j}))$$

I even implemented the above and tried to check it with computer simulations to see if the derivation was correct (and numerical derivatives too, i.e. really good approximations). I implemented this equation (twice) in MATLAB and couldn't get any of the different ways I implemented it to agree on the value of the derivative, so either my implementations are wrong or the equation is wrong. I actually made a stackoverflow question for that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31843929/how-does-one-vectorize-nicely-in-matlab-the-following-partial-derivative-with-re) if you want to take a look at it.

---

Actually, to make the equations and derivations more clear, I decided to draw a diagram/"network" of how the different variables down the recursion tree relate to each other (obviously, notice its only 4 layer recursion tree for this question):

[image]

Obviously, I've omitted some of the connections between the variables to not make the diagram to cluttered.

Comment: I changed what looked like some typos to me. Usually I would have pointed them out instead of going ahead and changing them myself, but in this case it would have been rather impractical to describe them :-). Please check [the edit history](http://math.stackexchange.com/posts/1386958/revisions) to make sure that they were indeed corrections and not misunderstanding or errors on my part.

Comment: Quite apart from the putative typos, I don't understand where $2(y-f(x))$ is coming from. It seems you forgot to introduce $y$, but independent of what exactly $y$ is, that entire factor seems to be just tacked on at the front of what you later (as far as I've checked, correctly) calculate for that derivative.

Comment: @joriki your corrections seem in fact, correct. So many indices and copy pasting probably lead to those mistakes. Thanks for the corrections. I couldn't quite catch if there was anything else wrong. Hope not. For the 2(y  - f(x)), is because there is squared loss I am trying to minimize. That shouldn't have been there since that really isn't relevant to my question. I deleted. Hope there isn't another typo like that.

Comment: Some things you can try: a) Create the simplest possible test case, e.g. all dimensions $1$ (whereever that makes sense), and see whether that makes it simple enough to compare results by hand; b) Take numerical derivatives to see which, if either, of your implementations is correct; c) Write it up e.g. in Sage, take the derivative symbolically and compare.

Comment: @joriki for ur first suggestion, b) what do u mean by numerical derivative? currently what I am doing is sort of using the definition of a limit and choosing a really small epsilon to see if it works. It works for other derivatives I've done but not for this one unfortunately. Or did you have something else in mind? c) sorry if this is a dumb question, but what do you mean "Write it up"? Didn't I write it up here on the math.stackexchange? Btw, thanks for ur help so far! I appreciate it! :)

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant, a small $\epsilon$. If that doesn't agree with either of your implementations, I'd try to combine that with the "simplest test case with lowest possible dimensions" approach. By "write it up in Sage" I just meant "express it in Sage", so that you can let Sage perform and compute the symbolic derivatives for you. (If I understand your Matlab code correctly, you're not differentiating symbolically there, just implementing the derivative that you derived by hand?)

Comment: @joriki omg, I didn't know something like sage existed. lets see if I can use this thing to help me. Btw, thanks for the suggestion. I will keep working on it and yes, I only implemented the equation I derived by hand above (cuz I wasn't even aware what sage was until now).

Comment: @joriki out of curiosity, is there are a reason why you recommended Sage and not mathematica or wolfram alpha?

Comment: Yes. I love Wolfram|Alpha and I often link to it in answers to show small to medium calculations, but it sucks at big calculations; it doesn't follow a formal grammar (since it's simultaneously trying to parse questions as natural human language) and gets thrown off if expressions get too complicated. (It also has a character limit.) Mathematica has a formal grammar and could do this, too; I just suggested Sage because it's free and open source and you can go right ahead and use it without buying it, and then you can link to a notebook to show your work to other people without them buying it.

Comment: @joriki my research lab actually has mathematica made available to us. Do you think it might be able to handle this problem symbolically (or even numerically)? (I don't actually know how to use mathematica...so lets see how long it takes me to check this haha, hopefully not too long, btw, thanks so much man :D )

Comment: Yes, you can do it in Mathematica -- just that others who don't have Mathematica won't be able to build on it. In fact I would have thought that Matlab, too, should be able to do this, but I know even less about that than about Mathematica.

Comment: @joriki so good news. It seems mathematica agrees with my derivation! (except for a minus sign that was easy to fix). Thanks so much jorki! :D :D

Comment: Great news; well done! :-)